# Erro ao exportar banco do SQL Server para outro Servidor

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, windows

Tenho um banco em um servidor  SQL Server Web Edition (64-bit) (11.0.5556.0) e preciso exportar ele para um servidor com  SQL Server Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) (10.50.4297.0).

Ao exportar os dados usando o SQL Server Export and Import Wizard encontro o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu estou achando que o erro acontece ao converter campos 'datetime' para 'smalldatetime'

O formato de data no campo que da erro (LastLockoutDate) é este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E quando vou exportar o banco e clico em preview de como será depois de exportado o formato fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso precisem de mais alguma informação, favor comentar abaixo, que eu edito a pergunta.

Comment: Vou colocar como comentario porque não sei se daria uma boa resposta. Mas eu já tive esse problema. E pra resolver eu exportei os dados do banco pra uma planilha do excel e depois importei os dados da planilha pra outro servidor. Assim dessa forma funciona de forma mais tranquila. Não sei se isso te ajudaria, mas não custa tentar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que posso te sugerir seria editar os mapeamentos durante o assistente de importação e exportação do sql server.

[image: Imagem002]

Você pode alterar o tipo do campo, ou ainda mandar ele regerar a tabela, que acredito que consequentemente irá gerar com o tipo do campo que você precisa e com as propriedades definidas no banco de dados de origem.